# C++: Easy way to convert project using macro strings to dynamic variable?

Tags: c++, macros, string-concatenation

I'm working on an old project that used #define to declare paths on disk this way:

```
#define APPPATH         "c:\\ProgramPath"
#define SEPARATORPATH   "\\"
#define DATAPATH        "data"
#define CONFILEFILE     "config.dat"
```

and about a thousand places in the code, they are used as literal string concatenation like this:

```
std::ifstream f(APPPATH SEPARATORPATH DATAPATH SEPARATORPATH CONFILEFILE, std::ios::binary);
```

Obviously, this is not the perfect way to do it. My main problem currently is the hardcoded APPPATH. I would like to allow the program to be executed from any directory on the disk, and replace APPPATH with the executable location (GetModuleFileName on Windows).

My question is, is there a way I can do something easily to do that without having to modify the thousand lines referencing the macro? Because for now, the only way I can find is to change it to a global const char* variable initialized on startup, and then replace all lines manually to add a strcat() around the macro list.

Comment: Have APPPATH defined as a variable (std::string) for the location with a + at the end of the defination.

Comment: You can probably use just `std::ifstream f(DATAPATH SEPARATORPATH CONFILEFILE, std::ios::binary);` if you make sure your working directory is the same as the binary file. The two easiest ways to that are to launch it from there with Explorer or to create a shortcut. You can set working directories on shortcuts.

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but for many cases it might be ok, if you replace the path with the name of a std::string variable you are using followed by a `+`.  Thid will change the type of the expression from a char array to a std::string though.

Comment: Don't use macros, and don't use backslash. Use runtime string concatenation. Or better, use the Boost filesystem library.

Comment: @Alf:  It's not *his* fault he has inherited a significant codebase that uses macros.  If it has grown from C code, I would even say that was a reasonable decision.

Comment: How much variations of this concatenations are there in place? Wouldn't a few regex replace operations solve the problem? The "solution" proposed by George Houpis and me is - in my opinion - a pretty dirty hack.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Using std::string and adding a + after each reference wouldn't work directly because you need to call .c_str() to get a char* afterward. We don't always use the string in a ifstream function parameter. I'm gonna try with coladict solution to see if I can get somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation, replacing APPPATH from "c:\ProgramPath" to "." worked fine. Not applicable if your goal is not the application path.